# Vestígio de clique de mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Preciso de um script, que em toda uma página onde se clicar apareça uma bolinha no lugar onde foi clicado, mas que depois de uns 2 segundos desaparecesse.

Não precisa ser ondinhas, apenas algo que deixe um vestígio, um exemplo é o Google Maps quando se clica no mapa aparecem ondas brancas para dizer que você clicou aqui.

No lugar da bolinha pode ser também uma imagem qualquer.

Comment: Você quer isso em qualquer elemento da página ou em elementos específicos? Se for em elementos específicos basta você definir um [tag:css] diferente para os links visitados `a:visited`

Comment: Em qualquer elemento, mas não entendo como o css que você sugeriu poderia me ajudar, mesmo se fosse em elementos específicos, poderia explicar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode criar um elemento com posicionamento absoluto, e usar `pageX` e `pageY` para obter a posição do clique do mouse. Aí é só colocar esse elemento nessa posição:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    $(novoElemento).appendTo("body").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top:e.pageY,
        left:e.pageX
    }).show().delay(2000).hide(0); // O zero é importante, ou o delay não funciona
});

// Alternativa: setTimeout
var bola = $(novoElemento)...
setTimeout(function() {
    bola.hide().remove();
}, 2000);
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/u96Cz/7/). (Nota: minha resposta anterior sugeria `clientX` e `clientY`, mas isso não funciona se o conteúdo for grande a ponto de aparecer a barra de rolagem)

Comment: Cara muito bom, mas o que eu queria mesmo era que depois de algum pequeno tempo ela(bolinha) desaparecesse.

Comment: @SamirBraga É só escondê-la (ou removê-la) depois de um tempo. Tentei usando `.delay` mas não funcionou, então aí vai um exemplo com `setTimeout`: http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/u96Cz/2/

Comment: Muito bom, valeu mesmo.

Comment: @SamirBraga Descobri o problema do `delay`: se você usa `hide` sem passar argumentos, ele se aplica imediatamente (i.e. mostra e logo em seguida esconde). Passando um número de milissegundos, mesmo que seja zero, ele funciona como deveria (só esconde depois que o delay termina).

Comment: Eu coloquei os milisegundos, mas valeu.

Comment: Muito legal! Mas não pude resistir em fazer uma [versão mais "fresca" com alguns efeitos](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/2U28P/). Estou sem votos agora, mas daqui a umas 3 horas +1 para a resposta!